# Why does it say that the Queue is empty when it isn't?

Tags: python, list, function, queue

You can see in the iteration before It prints the Queue out, but when it goes to remove the first term, it says that the list is empty, I don't understand why.

[image]

```
                while DistanceToEndOfCorner >= 0:

                Outputs(Speed, Distance, Time1)

                Speed, Distance, Acceleration, Time1 = ConstantSpeed(Mass, Speed, Distance, Acceleration, Time1)

                DistanceToEndOfCorner = SilverStoneCornersEnd[0] - Distance

                print("This is the distance to end of corner", (DistanceToEndOfCorner))

                print(SilverStoneCornersStart)
                print(SilverStoneCornersEnd)
                print(SilverStoneCornerRadi)

            while DistanceToEndOfCorner <= 0:

                SilverStoneCornersStart.pop(0)
                SilverStoneCornersEnd.pop(0)
                SilverStoneCornerRadi.pop(0)

                CornerNear = 0

                break
```

This is the section which is breaking, I tried without a while loop and some other ways but I kept getting this error. When i tried to pop the element at the start of the function it worked and I'm not sure what would be causing it to become empty because no where else in the code is there anything which pops lists.

Comment: Please update your question with all text and not images of text. Also please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: fix the indentation

Comment: Based on the code, `while DistanceToEndOfCorner <= 0:` holds forever (`DistanceToEndOfCorner` is not changed anywhere) so you are `pop`ing several times until you reach empty list and the error